# postgresql how to check by two columns from join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

There are some `points` and `point_types` with mark `actual`:

```
points
------
id  point_type
------
1   1
2   1
3   2

point_types
------
id  actual
------
1   true
2   false
```

Also there are `directions`:

```
directions
------
id  point_from  point_to
------
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   1           3
4   2           1
5   2           2
6   2           3
7   3           1
8   3           2
9   3           3
```

I need only `directions` with actual `point_from` and `point_to`:

```
id  point_from  point_to
------
1   1           1
2   1           2
4   2           1
5   2           2
```

Trying with:

```
SELECT d.id, d.point_from, d.point_to
FROM directions d 
JOIN points p ON (d.point_from = p.id OR d.point_to = p.id)
JOIN point_types pt ON pt.id = p.TYPE AND pt.actual = TRUE
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

but getting `directions` with actual `point_from` or actual `point_to` :

```
id  point_from  point_to
------
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   1           3
4   2           1
5   2           2
6   2           3
7   3           1
8   3           2
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your problem is kinda cryptic to me... Can you explain what's the purpose of this? Why are you trying to join either the from point to a point **OR** a to point to a point? why not both? why grouping by "1,2,3" what's the purpose of this?

Comment: aymcg31, "OR" to get actual mark from other table, if use "AND" in the result there will be only directions like 1-1, 2-2 and so on. The grouping is for geting unique directions.

Comment: forpas, thank you, edited question. In other words the result directions should be without point = 3.

Comment: forpas, yes, your're right, sorry, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns all the ids of the not actual points and then with NOT EXISTS get only the directions that do not contain any of them:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT p.id 
  FROM points p INNER JOIN point_types pt 
  ON pt.id = p.point_type
  WHERE pt.actual = false
)
SELECT d.*
FROM directions d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte c WHERE c.id IN (d.point_from, d.point_to));
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=246d3bd0cfdf753d3fb9365072a0b828).